# Mvc url Routing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-8.1, iis-8.5

How to route url

```
 http://localhost:5330/Admin/
```

to

```
 http://localhost:5330/Admin/Index
```

as i am getting

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

while trying to to call @Url.Action("Index","Admin") its redirecting to

```
 `http://localhost:5330/Admin/`
```

and showing the error but if i go to url and add like below it  works fine

```
http://localhost:5330/Admin/Index
```

Comment: Check your RegisterRoutes method and see what is defined there?

Answer (score 0):

----------- Update
try this,
You can just add custom routes for your specific need.
just copy n paste below code and add it to your Routeconfig.cs for your current requirement.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Admin",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

---

Seems like you have hosted your website/web application on IIS but you did not specify any default page to load or did not enable directory browsing or also please check your default routing configuration.

Comment: i ma just running it in my Local system. i havnet published it

Comment: can u please check with my updated answer, hope it will work, if not then please let me know !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a default value. In your solution, by default there's a folder named `App_Start`, containing a `RouteConfig.cs`. That will contain a class that looks something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

That part where it says `action = "Index"` in the `defaults` object is setting a default action. When the URL doesn't specify a URL, it will look for one called `Index()`. If you've altered your routes, check that you still have a default like this - and make sure they're in the right order. Routes are checked in the order you specify them, so you should always put the most specific routes at the top and the more general ones afterwards, to avoid a general route catching things that should go to a more specific one. A catch-all default like this one should be the last one you specify.

Comment: Copied the same but no luck

Comment: what if i want to write a seperate route to Admin controller  How to do it?

Comment: Add a second call to `MapRoute()` above that one, with the same `action = "Index"` part in the `defaults` object. That default is the important part here.